# CGVectorMake is unavailable in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a code snippet:

```
hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 250))
```

I get this error for this line:

> CGVectorMake is unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Swift 3 it has changed to `CGVector()`

```
hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    hero.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 250))
}
```